# How many themes can I create in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

How many themes in layers box can I create in QGIS 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the QGIS Documentation:**

> You can create as many map themes as you need: whenever the current combination in the map legend (visible layers, their active style, the map legend nodes) does not match any existing map theme contents as defined above, click on [Add Theme] for a creation or use Replace Theme ‣ to update the map theme.

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#map-themes

So in answer to your question -- "As many map themes as you need" i.e. there is no limit.

**Edit:** Added link to referenced QGIS Documentation

Comment: My QGIS "Add theme" was locked. Thanks.